# Axios patch request not working as expected

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to send a patch request without a body, so in Postman, I only require to send the request without body, but in the frontend, I need the second argument if not I will get a 401 error.

I've tried an empty string, NULL, and empty object - but it's still not working. It didn't return the same output as in Postman:

```js
export const somethingNeedsPatching = async (details) => {
  const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
  const url = `${
    import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SNATCH_URL
  }/something/somethingPath/${details.something}
  `;

  try {
    const res = await axios.patch(
      url,
      {},
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Content-Length": 0,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    return error.response;
  }
};
```

In Postman, the request is sent without a body and it works, but in the frontend, Axios requires a second parameter. If I left the url with the header, I'll automatically get a 401 error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFtJk.png)

Comment: What response do you get? What response do you expect? FYI, you probably don't want that newline at the end of your URL

Comment: I got a 500 error, saying that it cant read a property from my request.

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot showing your Postman request configuration?

Comment: sure I'll put it in the post.

Comment: The URL appears to end in a `/`. Is that important?

Comment: thank you , that's the error all a long...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is that your URL has a trailing newline. Also, the URL in the screenshot has a trailing `/`.

You also have redundant headers `content-type` and `content-length`.

In order to set no request body, you should be able to pass `null` or `undefined`. Alternately, use the general `axios()` method without setting a `data` property.

Separating `baseURL` and `url` can also make your code cleaner

```js
const res = await axios.patch(
  `/something/somethingPath/${details.something}/`, // no newline, end in "/"
  null,
  {
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SNATCH_URL,
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  }
);

// or

const res = await axios({
  method: "patch",
  url: `/something/somethingPath/${details.something}/`, // no newline, end in "/"
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SNATCH_URL,
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});
```

Comment: I still got the same error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'disableDate'), status code 500

Comment: @SyedAbuHanifahBinSyedAzmi I've updated my answer based on your Postman screenshot

Comment: it's been solved The only thing im missing was the / at the end

Answer (score -1):

I think may be due to the url also you may get the error so you may try as:

```
const url = `${
process.env.VITE_APP_SNATCH_URL
```

}/something/somethingPath/${details.something}
`;

and in header too you have to remove the content-length line and should try this as:

```
     headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: but im using vite and to use env, that's the convention i have to follow